# java chat socket when receive the message, it doesnt show on client

Tags: java, sockets, server, client

good evening, i tried to make a java chat client/server , between 2 persons, everything is working good, except i cheated in a line of code, i wanted to know what should i do to make a correct work. (i will mark the problem line of code)

```
package sockets;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Client
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, Throwable
    {
    Socket s;
    BufferedReader in;
    PrintWriter out;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    s = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 9000);
    System.out.println("Connection pending");
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
    out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
    ReceiveMessageThread thread = new ReceiveMessageThread(in);
    String msg = in.readLine();
    System.out.println(msg);
    thread.start();
    while (msg != "")
    {
        msg = sc.nextLine();
        out.println(msg + "\n");
        out.flush();
    }
    s.close();
    sc.close();
}  
}
```

===========================================

```
package sockets;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class TClient extends Thread
{
private int num;
private Socket s;
private BufferedReader in;
private PrintWriter out;
private JFrame frame;
private JButton button;
private JTextField txt;
private JTextField named;
private JTextArea chat;

public JTextArea getChat() 
{
    return chat;
}

public int getNum()
{
    return num;
}

public void setNum(int num)
{
    this.num = num;
}

public Socket getS()
{
    return s;
}

public BufferedReader getIn()
{
    return in;
}

public String getTxt() 
{
    return txt.getText();
}

public String getNamed() 
{
    return named.getText();
}

public PrintWriter getOut()
{
    return out;
}

public TClient(Socket s, int num) throws IOException
{
    this.s = s;
    this.setNum(num);
    System.out.println("Client " + num);
    out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
    out.println("Connected " + num + "\n");
    out.flush();
    frame = new JFrame("Chat in sockets");
    button = new JButton("Send");
    txt = new JTextField();
    chat = new JTextArea();
    named = new JTextField();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(500, 500);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLayout(null);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.add(button);
    frame.add(chat);
    frame.add(txt);
    frame.add(named);
    button.setVisible(true);
    button.setSize(85, 74);
    button.setLocation(375, 391);
    named.setVisible(true);
    named.setSize(100, 25);
    named.setLocation(5, 2);
    txt.setVisible(true);
    txt.setSize(365, 75);
    txt.setLocation(5,391);
    chat.setVisible(true);
    chat.setEditable(false);
    chat.setSize(455, 355);
    chat.setLocation(5,30);
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            sendMessage(named.getText()+" : "+txt.getText()+"\n");
            chat.append(named.getText()+" : "+txt.getText()+"\n");
            txt.setText("");
        }
    });
}

public void run()
{
    while (true)
    {

        try
        {
            String msg = "";
            msg = in.readLine();
            System.out.println("client(" + getNum() + ")" + msg);
            chat.append("client(" + getNum() + ")" + msg);
            sendMessage(msg);
            if (msg.equals("."))
                break;
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    try
    {
        s.close();
    } 
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void sendMessage(String message) 
{
    int client = (getNum()-1)==1 ? 0:1;
    Server.send(client, message);
            System.out.printf("Sending message(%s) to client:%d from client:%d%n",message,client,getNum());
}
}
```

=========================================================

```
package sockets;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Server
{
static TClient[] connexions = new TClient[2];

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ServerSocket ss;
    Socket s = null;
    int nb_clients = 0;
    try
    {
        ss = new ServerSocket(9000);
        System.out.println("Server is listening in:" + ss.getLocalPort());
        boolean continu = false;
        while (!continu)
        {
            s = ss.accept();
            connexions[nb_clients] = new TClient( s, nb_clients + 1);
            connexions[nb_clients].start();
            nb_clients++;
            if (nb_clients > 2)
                continu = true;
        }
        System.out.println("Clients connected");
        s.close();
        ss.close();
    } 
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void send(int clientNum, String message) {
    TClient t = connexions[clientNum];
    if(t != null) 
    {
        t.getOut().println(message);
        t.getChat().append(message);//this line is not correct even it shows a correct result
        t.getOut().flush();
    }
}
}
```

============================================

```
package sockets;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ReceiveMessageThread extends Thread 
{
private BufferedReader in;

public ReceiveMessageThread(BufferedReader in) 
{
    this.in = in;
}

public void run() 
{
    while(true) 
    {
        try 
        {
            String message = readMessage(in);
            if(message!=null && !message.equals(""))
            {
                System.out.println(message);
            }

        } 
        catch(IOException ie) 
        {
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public String readMessage(BufferedReader in) throws IOException 
{
    String msgreceived = "";
    String readValue = "";
    while(in.ready()) 
    {
        readValue = in.readLine();
        if(readValue !=null)
            msgreceived += readValue;
    }
    return msgreceived;
}
}
```

Comment: You never specified a problem. Also, that is a lot of code. Create a small program that reproduces the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
 while(in.ready())
```

Usual misuse of this method. The loop will only execute if there is something to read, which may not be true yet: you may need to block. Change it to

```
while (true)
```

and if you get `null` from `readLine()`, return null so that the caller knows the peer has closed the connection.

Comment: the problem is not here, it is in server

Comment: t.getChat().append(message); this is my problem, it seems not right to use it like that